# I just built a static library in VS 2010, how can I determine the exported symbols?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, intel-fortran

I am using Intel Fortran Composer XE.  I just built a static library which I'm trying to link against using the MS Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler.  Since my linking step isn't working, I want to list the symbols in my Fortran library to make sure that the name is mangled in the expected way. What is the easiest way to get a symbol list out of the library -- short of downloading and installing cygwin to get a 64-bit version of nm.  Note that I am build/compiling/running on x64 (Windows 7).

Comment: M. Tibbits - I don't know the answer to your question, but if you're in a time jam, may I suggest posting it on Intel's forums and on comp.lang.fortran; bound to get an answer sooner and better than here. Also what is nm?

Comment: nm is a Linux utility to list the exported symbols within an object file.  I'll try their forum, but I don't have a support contract -- I'm evaluating their product on a trial basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dumpbin /symbols libraryname.lib
```

Dumps out all symbols in the library.

Comment: I'm giving Kynth the bounty since he responded first.  You're both correct.  So I'm accepting your solution -- I wish there was a way to split a bounty between two people.

Answer (score 1):

Does [dumpbin with symbol support enabled](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=29) give you what you need?